# Why does the looping statement go wrong when the 10th loop ends in a C program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to calculate the series'approximation, and I set accuracy as 1E-6.

```
int i=1;
    float x;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    double sx = x,temp;
    do{
        temp = (pow(x,((2*i)+1)))/((2*i+1)*(fact(i))); //fact() is a function counting factorial
        if((i+2)%2==1) sx-=temp;                        
        else sx+=temp;
        printf("%lf %lf\n",temp,sx); 
        i++;
    }while(temp>1E-6);
    printf("%lf",sx);
```

When the input is smaller than 2, I get expected output.But When the input comes to 3, there is a negative number. Is that because of stack overflow? But fact(10) isn't so big, is it? How I can get the right result?

[image: Series]

Comment: A stack overflow would presumably lead to a noisy error. That said, you should really post your `fact` implementation.

Comment: Without [mcve] I can only speculate (but with high confidence degree) that your `fact` is simply overflowing the integer.

Comment: Help us out - provide complete code we can try, provide expected output and actual output for an error example.  There are many more people that can help if you don't  require them to understand application to distinguish a right from a wrong answer.  Also the code for `fact()` is missing.

Comment: If `fact` returns an `int` or `long` you will eventually get an integer overflow either in the result of `fact` or when you multiply it with `(2*i+1)`. To debug this, split the calculation into smaller parts and print the intermediate results, especially the return value of `fact` and the result of `(2*i+1) * fact(i)`

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger?  Using `printf()` debugging is a poor substitute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exponentials and factorials grow very quickly, and often overflow integer types and cause precision issues even with floating point types. Mathematicians often do calculations like these in logarithmic space. The C math library has the function lgamma(), for example, that calculates the natural logarithm of the gamma function (gamma(x) = fact(x-1)), to a precision that might be lost if you had to represent the whole factorial first and then take the log of it.

So, assuming `double x` and `int n`, you can rewrite `pow(x,n) / (n * fact(n / 2))` as `exp(n * log(x) - log(n) - lgamma(1 + n / 2))`, and get reasonable results for large `n`.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void series(double base) {
    double x = base;
    double sx = x, temp;
    int i = 1;

    do {
        int e = 2 * i + 1;

        temp = exp(e * log(x) - log(e) - lgamma(i+1));
        if (1 == i%2) sx -= temp;                        
        else sx += temp;

        printf("%d %lf %lf\n", i, temp, sx); 
        i += 1;
    } while (temp > 1E-6);
}

int main(void) {
    series(3.0);
}
```

and the output:

```
1 9.000000 -6.000000
2 24.300000 18.300000
3 52.071429 -33.771429
4 91.125000 57.353571
5 134.202273 -76.848701
6 170.333654 93.484953
7 189.800357 -96.315405
8 188.404766 92.089362
9 168.572686 -76.483324
10 137.266330 60.783006
11 102.542831 -41.759826
12 70.754554 28.994728
13 45.355483 -16.360755
14 27.146262 10.785507
15 15.236934 -4.451427
16 8.051335 3.599907
17 4.018901 -0.418994
18 1.900832 1.481838
19 0.854220 0.627618
20 0.365648 0.993266
21 0.149418 0.843848
22 0.058409 0.902257
23 0.021883 0.880374
24 0.007871 0.888245
25 0.002723 0.885522
26 0.000907 0.886429
27 0.000291 0.886138
28 0.000090 0.886228
29 0.000027 0.886201
30 0.000008 0.886209
31 0.000002 0.886207
32 0.000001 0.886207
```

Comment: I have added tests to my answer and included your solution (as far as I understand it) - it appears to produce the poorest range of the expressions I  tested - may have got it wrong.

Comment: Yes, this does start to blow up when x gets to 7+, but so do the others. I'm not sure what this series is supposed to look like there.

Comment: When x is 8.0, the values for `temp` when `i` is 60..70 get into 26 digits, way beyond the precision of double, so even after they settle down all the precision has been lost. None of the methods will help with that. Too bad I can't do the addition in log-space.

Comment: Yes.  My point was not that it does not work for 3.0, but rather that it is useful for a smaller range than other solutions.  As it was suggested as an alternative to my fact() implementation, I had hoped it would be somehow superior.  It remains interesting, and an example of the care that must be taken with such things.

Comment: It is not so much the 26 digit number that is the issue, all double precision values are precise to about 15 _significant_ digits; it is rather the combination in the expression of both very large and very small values with different _magnitudes_ of precision.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked about whether 10! is too big, but had you observed `i` at the point the value overflows, you will see that `i == 12`.  The expression for `temp` then is then:

3<sup>25</sup> / 25 x 12!

The sub expression 25 x 12!  has value 11975040000 which would require 34 bits if it is an integer expression which it will be if `fact()` is an integer function.  If it is a 32 bit integer function, it will overflow.

If `fact()` is changed to a an unsigned 64 bit type, it gets further, but that is only good for 19! and the divisor sub-expression overflows at `i=18` (29 x 18!) before converging.

It will converge for `i = 3` using the following factorial function implementation:

```
double fact(int n)
{
    if (n >= 1)
        return n * fact(n - 1);
    else
        return 1;
}
```

With result 0.886207.  For arbitrarily large values of x you will need an arbitrary precision or "bignum" math library rather then built-in types.

Inspired by Lee Crocker's comment I tried various expressions (tested at [GDB Online](https://onlinegdb.com/ryBKEuFPH))

1) Based on my `double fact( int )` and less your the extraneous parentheses ;

```
double e = (2*i)+1 ;
temp = pow(x,e) / (e * fact(i));
```

Results for x = 1 to 9:

```
x: 1.0  s(x): 0.746824                                                                                                                          
x: 2.0  s(x): 0.882081                                                                                                                          
x: 3.0  s(x): 0.886207                                                                                                                          
x: 4.0  s(x): 0.886227                                                                                                                          
x: 5.0  s(x): 0.886227                                                                                                                          
x: 6.0  s(x): 0.889677                                                                                                                          
x: 7.0  s(x): 2453.707036                                                                                                                       
x: 8.0  s(x): 1055556860.115990                                                                                                                 
x: 9.0  s(x): -nan
```

2) Using `tgamma()` :

```
temp = pow(x,e) / (e * tgamma(i+1)) ;
```

Result:

```
x: 1.0  s(x): 0.746824                                                                                                                          
x: 2.0  s(x): 0.882081                                                                                                                          
x: 3.0  s(x): 0.886207                                                                                                                          
x: 4.0  s(x): 0.886227                                                                                                                          
x: 5.0  s(x): 0.886226                                                                                                                          
x: 6.0  s(x): 0.882858                                                                                                                          
x: 7.0  s(x): -83.077451                                                                                                                        
x: 8.0  s(x): 3729162898.780624
```

3) Using `lgamma()`:

```
temp = pow(x,e) / exp(log(e) + lgamma(i+1)) ;
```

Result :

```
x: 1.0  s(x): 0.746824                                                                                                                          
x: 2.0  s(x): 0.882081                                                                                                                          
x: 3.0  s(x): 0.886207                                                                                                                          
x: 4.0  s(x): 0.886227                                                                                                                          
x: 5.0  s(x): 0.886236                                                                                                                          
x: 6.0  s(x): 1.904565                                                                                                                          
x: 7.0  s(x): -322346.422518                                                                                                                    
x: 8.0  s(x): 5416428382.734000                                                                                                                 
x: 9.0  s(x): -nan
```

The results differ for `x = 6.0`, but all versions break down at around there.  Which is better I am not clear - `fact()` I suspect.  The standard library functions offer no significant improvement is any.

4) Added Lee's expression to test (if I've understood his answer correctly) :

```
temp = exp(e * log(x) - log(e) - lgamma(i+1)) ;
```

Result:

```
x: 1.0  s(x): 0.746824
x: 2.0  s(x): 0.882081
x: 3.0  s(x): 0.886207
x: 4.0  s(x): 0.886227
x: 5.0  s(x): 0.886245
x: 6.0  s(x): 2.892730
x: 7.0  s(x): 96596.597282
x: 8.0  s(x): -720878097610.696167
x: 9.0  s(x): -18109761159507625984.000000
```

For reference, my test code:

```
double s( double x )
{
    double sx = x ;
    double temp = 1.0 ;

    for( int i = 1; temp > 1e-6; i++ ) 
    {
        double e = (2*i)+1 ;

        // Uncomment one of the following:
        //temp = pow(x,e) / (e * fact(i));
        //temp = pow(x,e) / (e * tgamma(i+1)) ; 
        //temp = pow(x,e) / exp(log(e) + lgamma(i+1)) ;
        //temp = exp(e * log(x) - log(e) - lgamma(i+1)) ;

        sx += (i % 2) == 0 ? temp : -temp ;  
    }

    return sx ;
}

int main()
{
    for( double x = 1.0; x < 10.0; x += 1.0 )
    {
        printf( "x: %.1f  s(x): %lf\n", x, s(x) ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might also consider using the C standard math library `lgamma()` or `tgamma()`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker : That would not have occurred to me; you should perhaps post an answer of your own - deserves more than a comment perhaps.